# How to put specific dictionary values in dataframe columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

So I have a dictionary and a Dataframe with already determined columns. I'd like to place, for example, every first value of the dictionary in the second column and every second value in the last column. So I want to be able to specifically set the values.
Here is my dictionary and the already made DataFrame:

```
products = {"Piano": [500, "10/10"],
            "Table": [120, "9/10"],
            "Book": [7, "2/10"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Product Name", "Price", "Made in", "Product quality"])
```

I image something like:

```
df.column[1] = products["Piano"][0]
```

And the result to be something like:

```
       Product Name  Price  Made in  Product quality
Piano           --    500       --             10/10
Table           --      9       --              9/10
Book            --      2       --              2/10
```

Comment: Are you sure Table's Price should be 9 and not 120?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` and `reindex`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(products, 'index', columns=['Price', 'Quality'])
df.reindex(columns=['Name', 'Price', 'MadeIn', 'Quality'])

       Name  Price  MadeIn Quality
Piano   NaN    500     NaN   10/10
Table   NaN    120     NaN    9/10
Book    NaN      7     NaN    2/10
```